# How can I get a forwarded email to show the original senders email address?

Tags: email, office365, forwarding

Our emails are automatically forwarded to other staff members when they are on leave, but in the process it is removing the original senders email address from the message. The original emails are being forwarded via office 365 to an outlook inbox.

I can't find a setting in outlook via office 365 to forward as an attachment as part of auto forwarding so as to show the original email address and it is essential for our working practices that we have this. Is there a way to get the senders address showing??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly are you enabling forwarding? The behavior you’re describing is not normal. Forwarded emails do show the original sender. I suspect it’s how you have enabled forwarding. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/forward-email-from-office-365-to-another-email-account-1ed4ee1e-74f8-4f53-a174-86b748ff6a0e

Comment: That is the option I am using which is why I find it unusual that the source email address doesn't show. When it comes through it is only showing the address it was forwarded from (i.e. that of the agent who is off) and omits the original senders email. I found a guide for an older version which shows a setting you can change as 'use default encoding for all incoming messages', but the same setting doesn't appear on this version.

Comment: Default encoding is not related to forwarding. Check with your IT department. They’ve probably got some third party spam filtering system causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "forward", use "forward as attachment". This should make sure that the email of the original sender is always visible in the attachment. If you setup the rule from the "Rules and alerts" section this should be an option. If you do not need to see who the email was sent to in the first place you can instead "Redirect" it, this should also preserve the information about the email address of the sender.

The "Out of office" section can be used for automatic out of office replies, but in my experience, rules like the one you ask about are best made in the "Rules and alerts" section of MS Outlook.

Please also make sure that you only specify conditions in the rule which are possible to run on the server side, to make sure it runs while the recipient is on leave. If you specify conditions which can only be run locally, on your computer when Outlook is running, the entire rule will not run if your computer is not online with Outlook running. Outlook will indicate if the conditions you specify can only be run locally by adding this information to the rule once you try to save it.

An additional note: a rule to forward all emails without exceptions is always (currently, August 2022) run at highest priority, it seems. If you would like exceptions to this, that is to define which emails that should not be forwarded, you should specify at least one exception in the "forward all emails" rule itself. Just adding a separate rule and trying to assign it a higher priority (for example: emails from a@b.c should be put in the trash and no further rules should be run) will not stop a global "forward all"-rule from forwarding emails from a@b.c, it seems. Once the "forward all"-rule has an exception in it, additional exceptions and rules can be made and given higher priority and should run as expected.

Final advice: always try to verify that your rules work as expected before relying on them.